# Bounded integrals imply normal family for $f \in H(U)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Locally bounded Family](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6174/locally-bounded-family)

Let's take $F$ to be the set of all holomorphic functions on the unit disk $U$, for which each $f \in F$ has the property:

$\int\int |f(z)|^{2} dx dy \leq 1.$

where the double integral runs over $U$. Is $F$ a normal family?

Comment: I am pretty sure I want to show $F$ is uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $U$. I keep thinking $|f|^{2} \leq \int \int |f|^{2} dxdy$ ? Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6174/locally-bounded-family

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, $F$ is uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $U$, so Montel's theorem applies.  Your $F$ is the closed unit ball of the Bergman space $A^2(U)$.  An excellent reference on these is Duren and Schuster's *[Bergman spaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=5IAWL8MUGtQC)*, which includes what you want here in the beginning of Chapter 1.  (In the proof, there is a reference to [page 9 of Duren's earlier book *Theory of $H^p$ spaces*](http://books.google.com/books?id=fs4rPPcJ7HUC&lpg=PP1&dq=duren%20h%5Ep&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

The inequality given in [Theorem 1](http://books.google.com/books?id=5IAWL8MUGtQC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false) implies that $$|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}(1-|z|)}$$ for all $f\in F$ and all $z\in U$.  So given a compact set $K\subset U$, $\{|f(z)|:z\in K,f\in F\}$ is bounded above by $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}d(K,\partial U)}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal. To see it, write
$$f(re^{i \theta}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nr^ne^{in\theta}$$
Calculate the integral by writing $|f|^2 = f \bar{f}$, and we obtain the inequality
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|^2}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{\pi}$$

Thus, if $f \in F$, $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, $|z| \leq r <1$ we have
$$|f(z)| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|r^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt{n+1}} \sqrt{n+1} r^n \leq (1/\pi)^{1/2} (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)r^{2n})^{1/2}$$

and so $F$ is uniformly bounded on compact subsets, thus normal by Montel's theorem.

Comment: See also this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6174/locally-bounded-family